# Data burned as audio-cd

Tags: data-recovery

A backup cdrom of mine failed to mount, after... 
    `sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom`

My guess is that I forgot to use `mkisofs` before burning with `wodim`.

That would mean that the data of my file, `backup.tar.gz`, is encoded on track-01 of an audio-cd.

Is it possible to recover this data?

If so, how?

Cheers,
Starfox

Answer (score 0):

You might try [IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/download.php), which is supposed to run on Linux with Wine. I have no idea whether it is likely to actually work or not in this case.